# react-navigation: How to wrap navigationOptions in multiple screens

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am just wondering if I have to place `navigationOptions` in all screens. Something like this:

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  welcome: {
  screen: WelcomeScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    },
  },
  email: {
  screen: EmailLoginScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    },
  },
  password: {
  screen: FindPassWordScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    },
  },
  register: {
  screen: RegisterScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    },
  },
  agree: {
  screen: AgreementScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  }
  })
```

Can I wrap `navigationOptions` to all screens? But this will throw me an error.

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  welcome: WelcomeScreen,
  email:EmailLoginScreen,
  password:FindPassWordScreen,
  register: RegisterScreen,
  agree: AgreementScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible to apply setting to all route, you are just doing it wrong

here,

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  welcome: WelcomeScreen,
  email:EmailLoginScreen,
  password:FindPassWordScreen,
  register: RegisterScreen,
  agree: AgreementScreen,
},{
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
})
```